# What are the Fonts used in the uploaded/attached image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the Font used in the uploaded/attached image? The one marked/outlined with red ink!
Only the slanted one!
I have already tried every font search engine to be exact but no results!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off-hand I would say it's close to [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto) or [FF DIN](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/).